# Removing emty Space from Div

Tags: html, css

Am trying to get rid of a space in my divs that look like this [image: this] and if i try pushing the image up it work but the containers height wont change is there anyway to fix it i mean to make them align in the same position?

HTMl

```
    <div class="addtocart-holder shadow">
    <div class="cart-img"> <img src="img/product4.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="cart-image-details">
    <div class="cart-item-name">  <h3> Feather Dress With Embellished Lace Top</h3> </div>
    <div class="cart-item-details"> <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Price Before:</td>
        <td class="old">$200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Price: </td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>You Saved:</td>
        <td  class="saved">$100</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Shippment :</td>
        <td class="free">Free</td>
      </tr>
    </table> </div>
    <div class="cart-item-add"> <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Quantity:</td>
        <td class="old"><input type="text" class="form-control"  value="1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><div class="buy-ico"> Add To Cart</div></td>
      </tr>
    </table> </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.addtocart-holder{
        min-width: 700px;
        margin-top:100px;
        padding:5px;
        backround: #fff;

    }
    .cart-img, .cart-image-details{
        border:1px solid #f00;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
    .cart-img{
        height:190px;
        width:26%;  
    }
    .cart-img img{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;

    }
    .cart-image-details{
        width:73%;
    }
    .cart-item-name{
        width:100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    h3{
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align:center;
        margin: 5px 0;
        color:#888;
        font: italic normal 17px georgia;
        font-style: italic;
    }
    .cart-item-details, .cart-item-add{
        width:49%;
        border:1px solid #000;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    table{
        border:1px solid #fff;
        width: 100%;
        color: #888;
    }
    td{
        padding:4px;
        font-size:16px;
        font-weight:500;
    }
    .shadow{
         height: auto !important;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.31);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.31);
        box-shadow:         0px 0px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.31);
    }
```

Comment: Just made a fiddle of your issue. No changes, and it seems to work fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/JMC_Creative/mf3swo4u/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set `vertical-align` property of `.cart-image-details` to top.

```
.cart-image-details {
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u9mtyjoe/

The initial value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`, so changing to `top` will help you align divs properly.

Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Comment: Should be noted that this is *not* cause of a plain use of DIV elements, but cause the presence of the `inline` or `inline-block` rule assigned to that element.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan indeed, vertical align could only be applied to **inline-level** and **table-cell** elements.